# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) Code runs, though

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, token

i have searched over stackoverflow and most of topics related with my problem, but i couldn't find it.

The problem is explained in title.

May i ask for your help solving this?

`setTimeout(t2.style.transform="translateY(250%)", 1000);`

VM1470:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

https://jsfiddle.net/8jaa57tx/
(It doesnt seem to work on JSfiddle, but works in my browser)

Comment: `setTimeout(function () { t2.style.transform = "translateY(250%)" }, 1000);`

Comment: Reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) is always usefull.

Comment: I am new to JS and mostly newbie in programing, i'll look up inthese documentations, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` expects a function as the first argument. The way you've written it means that the transform will be updated immediately rather than waiting.

You can rewrite it with an anonymous function or a named function as follows:

```
setTimeout(function(){t2.style.transform="translateY(250%)";}, 1000);
```

or

```
function updateTransform() {
    t2.style.transform="translateY(250%)";
}

setTimeout(updateTransform, 1000);
```

Comment: Was just about to say this :) heres a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ehm1628h/